Problem about critical value for multiple comparisons
Consider a one-way layout of fixed effect model:
$$y_{ij}=\eta+\tau_i+\epsilon_{ij}, \epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2),i=1,...,k,\ j=1,...,n,$$
$\tau_i$ is the main effect, and we want to test $H_0:\tau_1=...=\tau_k$.
I need to use Tukey's method to do this, i.e.,
$$Reject\ H_0\ if\ |t_{ij}|>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ q_\alpha({k,nk-k})$$
$$where\ q_\alpha({k,nk-k})\ is\ the\ upper\ \alpha\ quantile\ of\ the\ SR\ distribution.$$
I know that after computing the mean of each group, we can compare their differences with this critical value.
For example, to compare treatment 1 and treatment 2, and $\overline{y}_{1\cdot}=1,\ \overline{y}_{2\cdot}=1.5$, then compare 0.5 with the corresponding critical value.
But we cannot use this critical value to compare these two means after observing their values.
For example, $\overline{y}_{1\cdot}=1,\ \overline{y}_{2\cdot}=2,\ \overline{y}_{3\cdot}=3,\ \overline{y}_{4\cdot}=4, \ \overline{y}_{5\cdot}=5,$ then we cannot always choose the largest difference to do the comparison (comparing 1 and 5 after observing they have the largest difference).
Because in this way we are indeed comparing the order statistics.
My question is:
If we want to compare treatment 1 and treatment 5 after observing their means, we only need to do "one test"----$H_0$: $\tau_1=\tau_5$, but which critical value should we use?
Also, I am not sure whether our $H_0\ is\ \mu_{(1)}=\mu_{(k)}$ ?
($\mu_i\ is\ the\ mean\ of\ treatment\ i, and \ ()\ denotes\ order\ statistic$)

In Tukey's method, you are comparing pairs of treatment means. So the null hypothesis is $H_0: \tau_i=\tau_j$ for $i\ne j$. The critical value is the same for every pair.
